# HTTP Downloader Spam Answers

Tags: discussion, moderation, spam

Just a heads up to reviewers tonight: there’s a newbie who has been posting answers to questions about large downloads. He has answered at least 5 other questions the same way: promoting his app. Here’s a sample of his answer. 
[image]

Comment: A regular spam flag on each post will get them into the general review queue, and other users will make short work of them. Adding a comment makes it easy for other users to see what's going on, and look for the other posts. A serial spammer is a separate issue, since you want a mod to take action with the user, independent of the posts. A custom flag will work for that, although those are seen only by mods, so that can delay getting rid of the posts. Another way is to use regular spam flags for the posts, and for the user, either one custom flag or post a comment on the Ask a Moderator chat.

Comment: BTW, for fastest action, include a link to the user and/or posts if you raise the issue in chat or here.

Comment: @fixer1234 I would’ve put a link, but I was on my phone. They’re gone now, thankfully.

Comment: He is up again https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206186/103727

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there's nothing left to do at this point. It has been flagged to oblivion.

*Amusingly* even if it wasn't spam, IIRC google take out files are only available for a limited amount of time, I don't think you can split them...

so... it would not have been that useful anyway.

In future though. On the books? Spam flag it. Reporting it to the [smoke detector team](https://charcoal-se.org/) would be useful too. More or less, keep calm, and quietly call for support fire ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's why Moderator is around and there is an option:

> in need of moderator intervention
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

Just raise flag with clear message. Why you think it's need moderator attention and move on. Moderator effectively handle that.

Comment: The key words in that option are **not listed above**. Spam is the first option on the list, and flagging the answers as spam will help get them taken care of more quickly.

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention would allow this spam to exist for longer and doesn’t result in an automatic downvote.  This means while the answer might eventually be deleted, if it isn’t downvotes, the author is able to continue to submit spam.

Comment: @duskwuff, if the answer is relevant but intrusive, you can't be sure it's spam. As I see on the screenshot, there is not just a link, but also information about how it solves a problem. Maybe comment to the author would be enogh for him to stop posting suh answers. Also in such case flag for moderator attention is more relevant that for spam.